# Given a role ARN, how do you find out which stack and region created the role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

Can anyone please provide CLI command to get the stack name and region that created a particular IAM role?

Answer (score 1):

you will have to write a small looping script that goes through all the region and all the stack (with let's say 'CREATE_COMPLETE' status) and use the describe-stack-resources CLI command.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/describe-stack-resources.html

Here is a small example:

```
#!/bin/bash

for region in us-east-2 us-east-1 us-west-1 us-west-2 ap-east-1 ap-south-1 ap-northeast-3 ap-northeast-2 ap-southeast-1 ap-southeast-2 ap-northeast-1 ca-central-1 cn-north-1 cn-northwest-1 eu-central-1 eu-west-1 eu-west-2 eu-west-3 eu-north-1 me-south-1 sa-east-1
do
        echo "Processing region $region ..."
        for stack in $(aws cloudformation list-stacks --stack-status-filter CREATE_COMPLETE --output json --region $region | jq '.StackSummaries[] | .StackId' | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//')
        do
                echo "Processing stack $stack ..."
                aws cloudformation describe-stack-resources --stack-name $stack --output json --region $region | jq '.StackResources[] | select(.ResourceType=="AWS::IAM::Role") | select(.PhysicalResourceId=="PUT_YOUR_ROLE_NAME_HERE")'
        done
done
```

Don't forget that if you have your role ARN you can easily get your account number and you role name. The format being

> arn:aws:iam::account-id:role/role-name

I hope that helps, sorry about the oneliner, it's less readable.

Comment: Thank you Nicolas Aizier

Answer (score -2):

aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name myteststack

Comment: sorry,unfortunately that din't answer my question. I have a created role using cloudformation template in one of aws region and i would want to get stack name and stack region through that role/role arn. can some one please provide aws cli command